# NetSuite List of Items by Bin

Tags: report, netsuite, inventory-management, saved-searches

I'm looking to create a list of all inventory items that we have. Most of our items are stored in 2 different geographical locations, and each location may have the same item stored in a primary bin (picking), and another bin (secondary storage bin).

I'm trying to get an export of all items, and the locations and bins that they are stored in. Each row would need to be a separate display of the item's quantity. I want to be able to see the detail of where all items can be found in our locations.

Desired output (columns separated by hyphens) For example:

Item 1 - Location 1 (WHS) - Bin AA2 - Qty 50 
Item 1 - Location 1 (WHS) - Bin ZZ9 - Qty 100 
Item 1 - Location 2 (Store) - Bin 30 - Qty 5 
Item 2 - Location 1 (WHS) - Bin AB3 - Qty 20 
Item 2 - Location 1 (WHS) - Bin ZA4 - Qty 13 
Item 2 - Location 2 (Store) - Bin 10 - Qty 10

I've tried running a Item saved search with the following columns:
Name 
Display Name 
Inventory Location : Name (To display the location where the item is stored) 
Location Available (this appears to sum up all quantities across bins at the location, so this is not working for me)

I've tried adding inventory detail fields, bin fields and all to no avail.

Anyone with experience out there that can tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to get the **"Bin On Hand"** fields:

You can get Location, Bin Number and On Hand from this join in your Saved Search.  When done your results fields should be:

- Bin On Hand:Location
- Bin On Hand:Bin Number
- Bin On Hand:On Hand

Todd Stafford

Comment: This worked and anticipated a need I hadn't thought of yet. Thanks!

Comment: my one month struggle to find a solution and this reply.
Thanks @todd

Comment: what if we need to get the lot/seriel numbers as well?

Comment: I had this same requirement. Thanks to OP and you for this answer!

Comment: how can i display Bin On Hand:location in the customization form "Sales Order Advanced PDF/HTML Template"

Answer (score 3):

From Admin role: List > Search > Saved Searches > New > Inventory Balance

In the results menu:

1. Item
2. Inventory Location
3. Bin
4. Quantity On Hand.

Comment: This did it. Thank you!

Comment: Awesome! If you wouldn’t mind accepting the answer, I would appreciate it! Happy Holidays!