# NetSuite PHP Saved Search Call for InventoryBalance type

Tags: php, netsuite

I have been using the `TransactionSearchAdvanced` to perform a lot of the save searches within the PHP Toolkit. Unfortunately, this is not working for one of my Inventory Balance saved searches. I have tried to look for any object with Inventory Balance Search Advanced within the NetSuiteService but I was not able to find it. Do you guys know which search object I should be using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, there is no Item Balance search object within the PHP Toolkit. Using the following sources, I was able to recreate the item balance saved search using an item saved search.

[image]

Sources:

- https://jcurvesolutions1.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/360033143712-Item-Saved-Search-Inventory-by-Location-with-Quantity-On-Hand-and-Value
- [NetSuite List of Items by Bin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65362746/netsuite-list-of-items-by-bin)
- https://www.reddit.com/r/Netsuite/comments/lwicd7/inventory_balance_search_phptoolkit/