# How to get the Record Type of a Saved Search in NetSuite

Tags: php, netsuite, suitetalk

I am trying to get the results of a saved search using the PHP Toolkit. I read that in the [documentation](https://1002555.app.netsuite.com/core/media/media.nl?id=1532&c=1002555&h=99a973e082c85f237b08&_xt=.pdf) :

`You can then use the search() operation, along with the <Record>SearchAdvanced object to return the details of the saved search.`

I am trying to find out what the `Record` is for an Inventory Balance search. I have attached a screenshot of how I set up the UI saved search.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, there is no Item Balance search object within the PHP Toolkit. Using the following sources, I was able to recreate the item balance saved search using an item saved search.

[image]

Sources:

- https://jcurvesolutions1.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/360033143712-Item-Saved-Search-Inventory-by-Location-with-Quantity-On-Hand-and-Value
- [NetSuite List of Items by Bin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65362746/netsuite-list-of-items-by-bin)
- https://www.reddit.com/r/Netsuite/comments/lwicd7/inventory_balance_search_phptoolkit/